# Is there an analog to Powershell's dir in .NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am looking for a built-in functionality in .NET to query folders with relative paths and wildcards, similar to Powershell's `dir` command (also known as `ls`). As far as I remember, Powershell returns an array of `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` .NET objects, which can later be used for processing. Example input:

```
..\bin\Release\XmlConfig\*.xml
```

would translate into several `FileInfo`'s of XML files.

Is there anything like that in .NET?

Comment: Um. `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo`? What analogue do you need? Those should do.

Comment: @Oded: I am looking for the right function to return an array/list/enumerable of FileInfo based on a filter.

Comment: Why didn't you look at either `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` MSDN pages then? First port of call and you would have found your answer.

Comment: @Oded: None of them work, as Powershell does it. For example, EnumerateFileSystemInfos does not seem to like a wildcard filter for anything else but file names. So this `..\Vic???\Doc*\*.pdf` would not return PDF files under `C:\Users\Victor\Documents` on my local machine, and just crash instead with `illegal characters in path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.IO.Directory` is the static class that provides that functionality.

For instance your example would be:

```
using System.IO;

bool searchSubfolders = false;
foreach (var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"..\bin\Release\XmlConfig",
                                                  "*.xml", searchSubfolders))
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath); //If you prefer
    //Do something with filePath
}
```

A more complex example would be: (note this isn't really tested very thoroughly, for instance ending a string with `\` would cause it to error)

```
var searchPath = @"c:\appname\bla????\*.png";
//Get the first search character
var firstSearchIndex = searchPath.IndexOfAny(new[] {'?', '*'});
if (firstSearchIndex == -1) firstSearchIndex = searchPath.Length;
//Get the clean part of the path
var cleanEnd = searchPath.LastIndexOf('\\', firstSearchIndex);
var cleanPath = searchPath.Substring(0, cleanEnd);
//Get the dirty parts of the path
var splitDirty = searchPath.Substring(cleanEnd + 1).Split('\\');

//You now have an array of search parts, all but the last should be ran with Directory.EnumerateDirectories.
//The last with Directory.EnumerateFiles
//I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.
```

Comment: What if I cannot separate a path into folder + extension filter? For example `..\bin\Release\XmlCon???\*.xml` ?

Comment: @Neolisk: I added the last parameter to show you how to use it.

Comment: Did you read my comment above? Your example assumes there will be a root path and I will be filtering only by file mask underneath. What if there is a folder mask as well? Powershell's dir handles such cases just fine.

Comment: @Neolisk: Ah, I thought you just wanted to search all of bin\release, which that flag controls. There is another method that allows enumerating file objects and should provide that functionality.

Comment: Well it solves the problem with `bin/release` (at least for now), but there is another one, which is related to how our legacy system keeps files (non-dotNET). For example, you can have `bla????` folders, where `????` is a random 4-digit number, and you need to include all those folders in deployment. So you would have filters like `c:\appname\bla????\*.png`.

Comment: @Neolisk: You could combine EnumerateDirectories with EnumerateFiles as a workaround. I don't see an easy way to include both at once.

Comment: You mean split by `\\` and process the filter manually via EnumerateDirectories and EnumerateFiles?

Comment: @Neolisk: Added an example of the beginning of that for arbitrary strings. You can just hard code the calls if you know the format of the string ahead of time. Alternatively you could skip my "largest starting point" logic and just do EnumerateDirectories for all the intermittent folders.

Comment: I got the point. Thanks for your help - will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383689.aspx) API:

```
var searchDir = new DirectoryInfo("..\\bin\\Release\\XmlConfig\\");
foreach (var fileSystemInfo in searchDir.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*.xml"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(fileSystemInfo);
}
```

The method will stream the results as a sequence of `FileSystemInfo`s, which is the base class for `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: VS complains that `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` does not exist in the current context. If I remove it and leave just two arguments, it says `an object reference is required for non-static member`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What about cases like `..\bin\Release\XmlCon???\*.xml`? It seems like `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` cannot handle them.

Comment: @Neolisk: Are you sure? The linked page shows ? and * as valid search terms.

Comment: @Guvante: Yes, I tried that. Problem is that if `?` and `*` are in the middle of the path, such as above, they are not considered valid.

Comment: @Neolisk: You'll need to search for all directories that match your intermediate path, and then search those directories for files.